# Executing update for MySQL with double byte makes field incorrect string

Tags: mysql, asp-classic, phpmyadmin, adodb, double-byte

MySQL is set as UTF-8(`utf8_general_ci`: MySQL, Table, Column).
I can **SELECT** varchar value as original double byte character via `ADODB` and `ASP`(Legacy VB Script). These characters are inserted from phpMyAdmin.

ASP pages are saved as `encoding Shift_JIS` and ADODB connection parameter is indicated as dsn=...;APP=ASP Script;`STMT=SET CHARACTER SET SJIS;`

But when I will **UPDATE** field from ASP, updated varchar string has **NO**(ommited) double byte character but has single byte character in phpMyAdmin.

How to fix these update/insert issue?
I tried to change MySQL charset to sjis but it wouldn't fix the issue.

Comment: OMG, what a mess of heterogeneous technologies!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could resolve the issue.
Route cause is in SQL.

> UPDATE users SET name = **N**'aaaa' WHERE id = N'BBB';

This 'N' makes characters boroken.
I was using ASP program with MS-SQL Server english version and this 'N' must be attached.
I must remove all these 'N's when move to MySQL from MS-SQL!